# git-p4 clone a single file

Tags: git, git-p4

I want to use git to do some temporary management of a specific file. There are many files in that directory structure that I don't want (and git would not handle well), but I need to use its patch management capabilities for this one file.

I want to use git-p4. Is it possible to clone one file instead of an entire directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

If it's only temporary, have you just considered doing git independent of perforce?

Just do `git init .` in the directory with the file, add the file to git, create a .gitignore for everything else, p4 edit the file to make it writable, and then use git for that file till you are ready to submit the file back to perforce.

That assumes you don't want/need the complex history and sync management that `git p4` gives you.